# посчитать количество html тегов в строке до спецсимвола

Tags: html, c++, строки

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


int recursive(std::string& htmlstring, std::string::size_type position)
{
    int tag_counter;

    while (htmlstring[position] != '#') // пока не встретится #
    {
        if (htmlstring[position] == '<')
        {
           continue; // нашли? Да, продолжим поиск.
        }
        else if (htmlstring[position] == '>')
        {
            tag_counter++;
        }

        position++; // увеличиваем позицию на 1

        tag_counter += recursive (htmlstring, position); // снова вызываем функцию с новым значением позиции
    }
    return tag_counter;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned int tag_counter = 0;
    std::string html_string("<td class=\"value\" ><div class=\"bestval\"><div class=\"test\">#<span class=\"test2\">None value</span></div></div></td>");
    for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i <= html_string.length(); i++) // для каждого символа
    {
        tag_counter += recursive(html_string, i);

    }
    std::cout << "Tags: " << tag_counter << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема: вроде бы алгоритм правильный, но реализация не получается.

Comment: вообще запутался в вашем коде) как работает инкремент внутри функции, если нет инициализации...зачем нужна рекурсия?

Comment: во первых назвать альгоритм правильный, когда там ошибка не одна, это самое большое заблуждение

Comment: да и вы понимаете, что при нахождении первого "<" у вас зациклится прога, потому что position не увеличивается. на самом деле я бы просто посчитал количество закрывающихся скобочек ">" как вам такой вариант? если я правильно понял, что вам нужно

Comment: Рекурсия нужна чтобы ходить по тегам.

Comment: @GarfieldCat но зачем? ладно, я вам переписал проще, товарищ его даже улучшил, пользуйтесь.

Comment: @GarfieldCat если вам помог ответ, пожалуйста, закрывайте вопрос, отмечая ответ как лучший

Answer (score 2, accepted):

все это можно свернуть в две строчки:

```
std::string html_string("<td class=\"value\" ><div class=\"bestval\">"
                            "<div class=\"test\">#<span class=\"test2\">"
                            "None value</span></div></div></td>");
size_t I = html_string.find('#');
size_t tag_counter =  std::count(html_string.begin(), html_string.begin() + I, '>');
std::cout << tag_counter;
```

Answer (score 1):

К студии доступа нет, но должно работать(опять же, если я правильно понял описание вашей задачи):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned int tag_counter = 0;
    std::string html_string("<td class=\"value\" ><div class=\"bestval\"><div class=\"test\">#<span class=\"test2\">None value</span></div></div></td>");
    auto position = 0; 
    while (html_string[position] != '#') // пока не встретится #
    {
        if (html_string[position] == '>')
            tag_counter++;
        position++;
    }
    std::cout << "Tags: " << tag_counter << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```